# Need to set logo in left side of Navigation bar in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

I am working on a swift project.In that i need the logo to be shown in left side of navigation bar and would like to make it globally in AppDelegate. But self.navigationitem is not detected in Appdelegate?Any Help would be appreciated as its my first project in swift.

```
     UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Constants.templatecolor
    let logoImage = UIImage.init(named: "logoImage")
    let logoImageView = UIImageView.init(image: logoImage)
    logoImageView.frame = CGRect(x: -40, y: 0, width: 150, height: 25)
    logoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let imageItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: logoImageView)
    let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    negativeSpacer.width = -25
    UINavigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems(negativeSpacer, imageItem)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the Navigation item in `AppDelegate`. Navigation item is the property of `UIViewController` or `UINavigationController` and you set the `UINavigationItem` for each ViewControllers.

If all that you wanna achieve is setting the navigation title for all screens declare a base class call it as `BaseViewController` n in `viewDidLoad` of `BaseViewController` set the navigation item

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let logoImage = UIImage.init(named: "close")
        let logoImageView = UIImageView.init(image: logoImage)
        logoImageView.frame = CGRect(x: -40, y: 0, width: 150, height: 25)
        logoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let imageItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: logoImageView)
        let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        negativeSpacer.width = -25
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer,imageItem]
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Now every single viewController in your project can extend from `BaseViewController`

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController {
  ...
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   }
}
```

Make sure you call `super.viewDidLoad` in `viewDidLoad`
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Sandeep.Will try but cant we customize the navigation bar to add logo image?

Comment: @ganesh : As far as I know u cant do it without the navigationItem instance and each viewController with embedded navigation controller gets its own instance of navigation item so u need to set the properties to each navigation item every time. Like adding a back button to parent will not result in child VC (one that is pushed on parentVC) to have back button isnt it ? Ill be surprised and will learn something new if somebody posts a way to customize nav bar in app delegate. Ill also keep and eye to learn something new :) till then the best solution that I could think of was inheritance :)

Comment: @ganesh : Did I get your question in comment correct ? U meant isnt there a way to globally configure NavBar so that it shows logo image correct? If thats the question my answer is added as comment above if not n u meant something else please lemme know

Comment: Just wanted to know if its possible using customising navigation bar.Your answer helped a lot and it worked.Thanks

Comment: @ganesh : Am glad it did :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Please change x position of logoImageView while setting its frame.
You are sets it's value as -40 might be because of that you are not able to see that logoImage.
Change it's x position to 0.